# Calculate time difference in minutes given specific date and time

Tags: java, date, datetime, difference

How would I calculate the time difference in minutes from the current time against a date/time in the format of "August 3, 2021 at 4:29 PM"?

Comment: You would use suitable classes from [`java.time`](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) for that.

Comment: Parse the date using a `DateTimeFormatter`. Then get the current time `ZonedDateTime.now()` and do `ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(first, second)`, done.

Comment: In which time zone is *August 3, 2021 at 4:29 PM*?

Comment: @OleV.V. U.S. Pacific Time

Comment: So you want `ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(ZonedDateTime.now(zone), LocalDateTime.parse("August 3, 2021 at 4:29 PM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, uuuu 'at' h:mm a", Locale.US)).atZone(zone))`. Only split over multiple statements. With `zone` set to `ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")` it just yielded `-1750`. A negative number since the time has past.